# Detecting contours of multiple faces via Firebase ML Kit face detection

Tags: java, face-detection, firebase-mlkit

I read somewhere for this https://developers.google.com/vision/android/detect-faces-tutorial lib that it can detect contours of only one face in picture. Than i updgraded for Firebase ML Kit in hope that they fixed that, but my code gets me only contours of one face in picture. Is there a way to detect all contours via ML Kit face detection? If there isn't, is there a workaround to do that? I don`t even think that i need all contours. I only need oval contours, so i know where the whole face is.

````
            FirebaseVisionFace face = myFaces.get(i);
            FirebaseVisionFaceContour contour;
            int k = 0;

            contour = face.getContour(FirebaseVisionFaceContour.FACE);
            List<FirebaseVisionPoint> points = contour.getPoints();
            for (int j = 0; j < points.size(); j++) {
                if (j < contour.getPoints().size() - 2) {
                    canvas.drawLine(contour.getPoints().get(j).getX(), contour.getPoints().get(j).getY(), contour.getPoints().get(j + 1).getX(), contour.getPoints().get(j + 1).getY(), mPaint);

                } else if (j == contour.getPoints().size()-1) {
                    canvas.drawLine(contour.getPoints().get(j).getX(), contour.getPoints().get(j).getY(), contour.getPoints().get(0).getX(), contour.getPoints().get(0).getY(), mPaint);
                }
            }
        }
        ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view)).setImageBitmap(finalProduct);```
````

Comment: Hi Got any ideas?

Comment: facing the same problem...any solution????

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android#1.-configure-the-face-detector) documentation, if you `setCountourMode` to `ALL_CONTOURS`, you can only detect the most prominent face in an image.
If you want to detect more than one face, you can `setContourMode` to `NO_CONTOURS`.